# how Producer thread infinitely generating data parallely

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, queue

how Producer thread should continuously generate data and run infinitely and put into  shared Queue and consumer continuously consume data object from shared queue in java

Comment: Producer thread should not sleep and keep on generating data set and put into shared queue. Parallely consumer has to consume data. here when consumer is accessing data it has to access whole object (contain data) and process it. Please guide me

Comment: yes, with infinite loop.

Comment: Try [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem)

Comment: Are you talking to yourself?

Comment: What have you tried, and what are you having trouble with?  You appear to understand what is required, so I suggest you go ahead and do it.